# Overriding or modifying a Java class constructor at runtime

Tags: java, reflection, overriding, loader

I have a class being instantiated as part of a sequence (a method goes through a random list of classes and creates 3 instances of each)

I am writing one of the classes in that list (note: all classes exist in the same package)

I am unable to modify the source files of any of the other classes and I need to either stop the instantiation of all classes following my own or override their constructor with an empty method.

I have so far tried using reflection, and have been looking at the classloader but cant figure out how to do this

I can gain a reference to the constructor with reflection but so far have been unable to interfere with it

edit -> a thought i had (dynamically re-write and recompile the target classes), code compiles but im getting an exception which stops the new class from compiling

```
private void reWrite(String name) {//throws IOException {
    try{
    File sourceFile = new File("/temp/" + "name" + ".java");
    System.out.println("file defined");
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(sourceFile);
    System.out.println("filewriter defined");

    writer.write("public class "+name+" extends Creature {/n"
            + "private static int instanceCount = 0;/n" + "public "+name+"() {/n"
            + " instanceCount++;/n" + "}/n" + "public void doTurn() {}/n"
            + "public final void creatureDestroyed() {/n"
            + " instanceCount--;/n" + "}/n"
            + "public final int getInstanceCount() {/n"
            + " return instanceCount;/n" + "}/n" + "}/n");
    writer.close();
    System.out.println("written");

    JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
    StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(null,null,null);

    fileManager.setLocation(StandardLocation.CLASS_OUTPUT,
            Arrays.asList(new File("/temp")));
    // Compile the file
    compiler.getTask(
            null,
            fileManager,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            fileManager.getJavaFileObjectsFromFiles(Arrays
                    .asList(sourceFile))).call();
    System.out.println("compiled");
    fileManager.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Print");
    }
}
```

edit-> the following is the code I am providing based on comments below

```
try {
        getW = (World.class.getDeclaredMethod("getWorld"));
        getW.setAccessible(true);
        theWorld = getW.invoke(World.class);
        getK = (Creature.class.getDeclaredMethod("die"));
        getK.setAccessible(true);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException exc) {
        System.out.println("Method Not Found.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("well shit");
    }

    try {
        f = World.class.getDeclaredField("locations");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        locations = f.get(theWorld);
        loc = (ArrayList<Creature>) locations;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("well poop");
    }
    if (loc.size() > 0 && !allMine) {
        for (int i = 0; i < loc.size(); i++) {
            if (loc.get(i).getClass() != Colonial.class
                    && loc.get(i).getClass() != Plant.class) {

                try {
                    getK.invoke(loc.get(i));
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }

                loc.set(i, new OpenLand());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You cannot "interfere" with a constructor through reflection: if you could, that would be a major security hole.

Comment: Please provide the smallest amount of code which illustrates what you are trying to do. The code should be complete enough that someone can copy and paste it and compile and run it to get the exact behavior which you are asking about. (Feel free to leave out import statements.)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight i figured reflection was a lost cause, am hoping there would be a way I could do it through the classLoader or with transformers, I have written a replacement classloader that would do the trick but the problem with that is that it has to be an internal class to mine, and I would need to replace the default loader with it at runtime

Comment: @Code-Guru wont help, let me explain my issue more, I am in a 3rd year Java OO-programming course for a software eng degree and our final lab is a "bugwars" where each team produces a bug by writing its behaviour (there are given constraints like organs they can grow etc) I have already produced the bug that will get marked, however we are invited to produce a "cheating-bug" which violates the rules.
I am trying to remove all bugs loaded after mine in the world populate method before they are loaded so that they cant remove me from the game as my bugs will have been loaded already

Comment: Giving us more information to help us to be able to answer your question won't help? I appreciate the extra context. Still code will make your question much more clear, not only to those of us who might be willing to help but to yourself as well.

Comment: @Code-Guru without uploading the entire project, not likely

so far what ive implemented is using reflection to gain access to the locations list in the projects "world" class and clear it of enemies, we do this in our constructor (will edit question to show that code) however all my attempts to interfere with the bugs that are loaded after ours have been complete failures and so i dont have any partially working code to present

I am hoping someone here can point me in the right direction, not necessarily provide me with the code itself.

Comment: Assuming subsequent bugs only spawn on `OpenLand`, why not replace any `Openland` with more instances of your bug? That might prevent further spawning. At the least it may give your bug a competitive advantage.

Comment: @Devon_C_Miller tried that, the way the populate method works it assumes there is open land available for spawn, and the program crashes if there is nowhere to spawn

Comment: Then maybe leave it just enough for it to run, but not enough for the other bugs to be dominant. Alternatively, wait for the first move/cycle/etc and terminate all the other bugs at that point.

Comment: @Devon_C_Miller I have that implemented already, the problem is that this is a cheating bug round and there is the chance that any bugs instantiated after mine could eliminate me in their constructor

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to modify the command line, you should try java agents. An agent is a class that basically hooks before the classloading and can modify the bytecode of a class.
In order to modify bytecode without being an JVM expert,  javassist is a nice library that allows you to write some java-like code and inject it before/after methods.
So basically, you need to

1. Write an agent that modify the constructor of your enemies classes
2. Launch the JVM using that agent

Here you have some minimal info about agents:
https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/how-to-make-java-more-dynamic-with-runtime-code-generation/
and javassist tutorials are really clear:
http://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/tutorial/tutorial.html
of course this is a dirty hack, but you asked for it

Comment: unfortunately the only thing i can touch is what is in my .java file

Answer (score 1):

You can use [sun.misc.Unsafe#allocateInstance(MyClass.class)](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/misc/Unsafe.java.html)  to construct instances without actually calling the constructor. See http://mishadoff.com/blog/java-magic-part-4-sun-dot-misc-dot-unsafe/ for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You don't *need* to 'interfere' with the constructor. It's fixed. You only need to *call* it, with `Constructor<T>.newInstance(...).` If there are other properties of the object you need to set, call the setters. If the setters don't exist, you can't do it.

Comment: i am trying to stop the existing constructor from being called, either by just stopping the instantiation or replacing/overriding the existing constructor with an empty one